# custom click to call implementation in mscrm 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

custom click to call implementation in mscrm 2013, currently dynamics crm 2013 built in support for Skype and lync. Is there any way I can override this behaviour so that call will be made from my telephony application. Is there customization support for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override the default behavior for phone fields that has Skype/Lync integration.

The alternative is to build a WebResource that will display the phone number and implement your click to call, or create a command button (ribbon) to handle the call.

Comment: I have to add a button just next to bussiness phone field and mobile phone field in a contact form. Can I place my web resource which contains dial  button and its script to dial a call just next to phone field. If I place it in ribbon, how would I determine which phone number to call.